# how to include jsp in a gsp page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, grails

i am trying to include a jsp, similar to how we include the jsp within jsp by using  tag. But couldnt get this working. Tried with the template as well http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Including-a-jsp-within-a-gsp-td1313927.html
didnt work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link you included, Graeme says:

> Its not possibly to a include a JSP within a GSP at the moment

Therefore, you **cannot do what you are asking**.  Why are you trying to mix a JSP in with a GSP?  A JSP is just a GSP with less functionality.

My guess is you have an existing JSP with a lot of non-display logic embedded in it.  If that's the case, **don't do that.**

JSPs and GSPs are for rendering the view.  They should never perform data lookup, or handle complex logic.  Those things usually should be handled by services within the controller (or in the controller directly in some cases), or wrapped up in tag libraries if they are part of the display logic.

If you want to include one page in another, you put the file in `grails-app/views/some/path/` and name it `_myfile.gsp`.  Then you include it using `<g:render template="/some/path/myfile/>`.  Note that the file must **start** with an underscore (`_`), and **end** with `.gsp`, but the template reference does not have either.

If you have existing JSP tag libraries, you can [reuse these in your GSP files](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#usingJSPTagLibraries), which might help.

Comment: You should be able to convert any JSP to a GSP with minimal effort.  When I've had to do it I copy/paste the JSP into a GSP file and go through and fix the errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clrification.

Comment: When you say " A JSP is just a GSP with less functionality" ... can you prove it? Or at least provide arguments. I've been looking for articles comparing pros and cons of each technology to no avail.